# How to set up and stop countdown interval

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having issues trying to stop my timer from stoping. I need it to stop when it get to 0. I am eventually going to use this timer to deduct 10 points for each wrong answer in the quiz. In addition, it will reset upon exiting the quiz. I am unsure on how to stop the interval from running. This is suppose to be a timed quiz activity for a bootcamp. Its not yet completed i am taking it step by step and want to get the timer working. Please help

```js
// ! functions to get elements
var startButton = document.getElementById('start-btn');
var timer = document.getElementById('timeDisplay')





startButton.addEventListener('click', startGame)

// ! start game function
function startGame() {
    console.log('started')
    startButton.classList.add('hide')
    countdown()
}

// ! timer function
function countdown() {
    var startingtimer = 10;

    var testtime = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(testtime)
        timer.innerHTML = startingtimer
        if (startingtimer > 0) {
            --startingtimer;
        } else {
            clearInterval(testtime)
        }
    }, 1000)

}


//  ! next question function
function setNextQuestion() {}

//  ! select answer function
function selectAnswer() {}


// ! Questions start
const questions = [{
        question: 'Commonly used data types DO NOT include:______',
        answers: [{
                text: 'strings',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'booleans',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'alerts',
                correct: true
            },
            {
                numbers: 'numbers',
                correct: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'The condition in an if/Else statement is enclosed with_____.',
        answers: [{
                text: 'quotes',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'curly brackets',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'parenthesis',
                correct: true
            },
            {
                numbers: 'square brackets',
                correct: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'Arrays in Javascript can be used to store_____.',
        answers: [{
                text: 'numbers and strings',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'other arrays',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'booleans',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                numbers: 'all of the above',
                correct: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'String values must be enclosed within ____ when being assigned to variables.',
        answers: [{
                text: 'commas',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'quotes',
                correct: true
            },
            {
                text: 'brackets',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                numbers: 'numbers',
                correct: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: 'A very useful tool used during development and debugging that prints content to the debugger is ____',
        answers: [{
                text: 'console.log()',
                correct: true
            },
            {
                text: 'terminal',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                text: 'for loops',
                correct: false
            },
            {
                numbers: 'javascript',
                correct: false
            }
        ]
    },
]
// ! Quetions End
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Gotham Rounded;
}

:root {
    --primary-color: rgb(105, 108, 150);
    --wrong-color: rgb(247, 89, 89);
    --correct-color: rgb(92, 241, 105);
}

.head-flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

body.correct {
    background-color: (--correct-color);
}

body.wrong {
    background-color: var(--wrong-color);
}

.container {
    width: 800px;
    max-width: 80%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
}

.btn-grid {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px
}

.btn {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(39, 39, 196);
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 5px
}

.btn:hover {
    border-color: black;
}

.btn.correct {
    background-color: var(--correct-color);
    color: white;
}

.btn.wrong {
    background-color: var(--wrong-color);
    color: white;
}

.start-btn,
.next-btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Quiz App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="head-flex">
            <a id="viewHighscore" href="#">View Highscores</a>
            <span id="time">Time: <span id="timeDisplay">0</span>
        </header>
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
            <div id="question">Question</div>
            <div id="answer-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Answer 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Answer 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Answer 3</button>
                <button class="btn">Answer 4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="start-btn" class="start-btn btn">Start</button>
            <button id="next-btn" class="next-btn btn hide">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./assets/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello check this hope it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869328/stop-countdown-timer-javascript-onclick

Comment: A better method is to just record the start time, and then update the display regularly (perhaps even with `requestAnimationFrame()` if your application requires it) with how much time has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have debugged your application, and I have just one error which is you missed a **var** at line 33

```
background-color: (--correct-color);
```

change that to:
background-color: var(--correct-color);
about your time it is working well and to ensure that it is working well I have created a function for stopping that timer **stoptimer(testtime)** and I have sent the timer also is working well.

```
// CSS CHANGES START
body.correct {
    background-color: var(--correct-color);
}
// CSS CHANGES STOP

// ! timer function
function countdown() {
    var startingtimer = 10;

    var testtime = setInterval(function () {
        console.log(testtime)
        timer.innerHTML = startingtimer
        if (startingtimer > 0) {
            --startingtimer;
        } else {
            // clearInterval(testtime)
            stopTimer(testtime)
        }

        //***** FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES ONLY *****/
        if (startingtimer == 7){
            stopTimer(testtime)
        }

    }, 1000)

}

//  The timer stop function
function stopTimer(myTimer){
    console.log("Stopping timer...")
    clearInterval(myTimer);
    console.log("Timer stopped...")
}
```

Please take a look at my sample, also let me know if it is not what you are looking for.
[image: I have added the resulting image]

Comment: when I console log it. the number is going up though not down. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: I will edit the answer and show you the result that I am getting. I also want to mention I have edited the debug to 2 then trigger stop.

Comment: thats good, but when I console log mine the timer is going down yes and it stops yes. However, the log isn't changing let me see if I can send image

Comment: @BrianMojica
I have created a chat so we can fix the problem together. at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/242955/room-for-awat-and-erikscandola?tab=general
can you join it?